# Assembly je, jns, jle which register does it use?

Tags: assembly, x86

Case 1:

```
cmp dword ptr[ebp + 18],00
mov eax, [ebp + 14]
je Game.exe+417442
```

Case 2:

```
test eax,eax
jns Game.exe+47137
```

Does it ALWAYS look at register eax? If not, how do we know what register it looks at to determine the jump?

Comment: Some instructions don't alter flags (mov in particular). So in case 1 the `je` is using the flags set by `cmp`. Case 2, `jns` is using the flags set by `test`.

Comment: In the first example it is not looking at `eax`. The instruction `mov eax,[...]` does not affect the `Z` (or any) flag, which was set by the previous `cmp` instruction.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am alittle confused. This is an independent flag right? It does not reside in any register? So at all times, there is only one flag for use in the whole assembly?

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand more now. I thought Z flag resides in eax for some reason. So is there only one Z flag for the whole program ?

Comment: The flags register resides inside the CPU. Various flags are affected by different instructions. You have to refer to the documentation of each instruction, to find out.

Comment: There is a single Z flag (same as others) for each processor on the system. The flags can also be observed by looking at the EFLAGS register (it is a bit pattern representing all the current values 0/1 for each of the flags)

Comment: Thank you so much! I learn something today : )

Comment: [Does a JE must follow directly to an CMP?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4436/2563)

Answer (score 6):

The x86 `Jcc` (where `cc` is a condition code) uses the [`(R|E)FLAGS` register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) to determine whether the condition is met or not.  The flags can be updated by various previous instructions.  In traditional x86 assembly you will often use a `cmp` or `test` instruction to write the flags before a jump instruction reads them.

If you look at the documentation for `cmp` at [this instruction reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp), and for [`test`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test), you will see that they permit any of the general purpose registers as operands.

I note that `cmp` and `test` are not the *only* operations that affect the flags, just, when you are writing your own assembly code, they are normally the operations you will use to determine if a jump condition is met.

Comment: `cmp` and `test` are commonly used to set flags, but so are *all* of the arithmetic and bitwise instructions. Beginners are just as likely to encounter those. In fact, they often make the mistake of performing an arithmetic or bitwise operation and then doing a `cmp` or `test`, not realizing that the latter is redundant.